# Using file text to proof TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox, text-files

I am trying to figure out how to use a text file full of acronyms to proof and auto-correct a list of keywords.  For example, I might have a list that looks like this in my textbox:

```
 nec 1080p television
 nec hdtv television
 nec lcd tv
 etc.
```

And in my text file, I would have something like this:

```
 LCD
 TV
 NEC
 HDTV
 etc.
```

What would be the fastest and most efficient method for comparing the acronym textfile to the textbox text (each of which could be 100s of lines long), and correcting any non-capitalized text in the textbox?  Any ideas?

Comment: is it a matter of only making them all uppercase or there is also spelling correction?

Comment: It would just be making them UPPERCASE, relative to the original list.

Comment: so if television is not in the original list, it should remain unchanged?

Comment: correct.  It is not in the Acronyms list, so it remains unchanged.

Comment: do you have a long list of acronyms ?

Comment: It could be any length...from a few dozen, to a few hundred.  That's why I was asking about the most efficient method.

Comment: The acronym list will almost always be shorter than the textbox list though.

Comment: check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/298519/Fast-Token-Replacement-in-Csharp) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textBox.Lines = ReplaceWithAcronyms(textBox.Lines, File.ReadAllLines(acronymsPath)).ToArray();

private static IEnumerable<string> ReplaceWithAcronyms(IEnumerable<string> lines, IEnumerable<string> acronyms)
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        yield return string.Join(" ", 
            line.Split(' ').Select(word => ReplaceWithAcronym(word, acronyms)));
    }
}

private static string ReplaceWithAcronym(string word, IEnumerable<string> acronyms)
{
    string acronym = acronyms.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac == word.ToUpperInvariant());
    if (acronym == null)
    {
        return word;
    }

    return acronym;
}
```

ReplaceWithAcronyms takes the lines of the textbox and the lines of the file where each line is one acronym.
It then splits each line into words and passes each word to ReplaceWithAcronym. If the word is one of the acronyms it will return that otherwise it will return the word unchanged.
The words are "unsplitted" by using string.Join. The result is converted to an array and then assigned back to the textboxes lines.

I didn't check how fast it is with hundreds of lines. To improve performance you can use a HashSet for the acronyms. I don't think that a few hundreds of lines are really a problem. Before trying to improve perfomance I would give it a try. Maybe it's good enough already.

Comment: I would suggest using [StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) instead. `string.Compare(string1, string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: Bob, why would you choose that and where would it go?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to finally get it to work.  I used the solution from Pescolino, and then called it with:

```
sortBox1 = ReplaceWithAcronyms(sortBox1, File.ReadAllLines(@"I:\acronyms.txt")).ToList();
```